# How to make div grid elements into a link and overlay with an image when hovering?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following HTML and CSS code:

```css
#project_section{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 300px 300px;
 grid-template-rows: 300px 300px;
 grid-column-gap: 150px;
 grid-row-gap: 60px;
 justify-content: center;
 
}
#box-1{
  background: LightSkyBlue;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}

#box-2{
  background:LightSalmon;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
#box-3{
  background:PaleTurquoise;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
#box-4{
  background:PaleGreen;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
.project_name{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id = project_section>
    
    <div id = "box-1"><p class = "project_name">link 1</p></div>
    <div id = "box-2"><p class = "project_name">link 2</p></div>
    <div id = "box-3"><p class = "project_name">link 3</p></div>
    <div id = "box-4"><p class = "project_name">link 4</p></div>
    
</div>
```

I'd like an image to appear over the each div "box" within my grid when hovering (that has the same dimensions as the existing box beneath it), clicking this image will take you to a link.

I've tried wrapping each div box in an anchor tag with an href = "#" as a start, but the boxes weirdly resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? Hope this helps.

```css
#project_section{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 300px;
  grid-column-gap: 150px;
  grid-row-gap: 60px;
  justify-content: center;

 }

.box {
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.box-1{
  background: LightSkyBlue;
}

.box-2{
  background:LightSalmon;
}
.box-3{
  background:PaleTurquoise;
}
.box-4{
  background:PaleGreen;
}

.project_name{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
}
.box:hover .project_link{
  opacity: 1;
}

.project_link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.project_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.project_link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<div id = project_section>
    <div class = "box box-1">
       <p class = "project_name">link 1</p>
       <a href="" class="project_link">
         <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/15/14/42/monkeys-768641__340.jpg" alt="" class="project_image">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class = "box box-2">
      <p class = "project_name">link 2</p>
      <a href="" class="project_link">
         <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/19/11/37/automobile-1838782__340.jpg" alt="" class="project_image">
      </a>
  </div>
    <div class = "box box-3">
      <p class = "project_name">link 3</p>
      <a href="" class="project_link">
         <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/04/03/09/24/cherry-blossom-4099835__340.jpg" alt="" class="project_image">
      </a>
  </div>
    <div class = "box box-4">
      <p class = "project_name">link 4</p>
      <a href="" class="project_link">
         <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/02/28/13/06/sea-4025901__340.jpg" alt="" class="project_image">
      </a>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

**So what I did is I tweaked some of your css and html. I noticed that you repeatedly used thesed properties `color: white; border-color: black; border-style: solid;` so I created a *.box* class to re-use these properties to avoid repeating.**

```
.box {
 color: white;
 border-color: black;
 border-style: solid;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
 -o-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

**I added this anchor tag with a *.project_link* class  and added the image inside it. And added a *.project_image* class on the image**

```
<a href="" class="project_link">
  <img src="yourimageurl" alt="" class="project_image">
</a>
```

**then styling the anchor and image, I added these lines**

```
.project_link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*not visible at first so that when 
   box was hovered it will make a popover effect*/
  opacity: 0; 
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
 -o-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease; // added a transition
}
.project_image {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
   position: relative;
}
.project_link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

**And finally to make the hover effect**

```
.box:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background: transparent; // make the background transparent 
}
.box:hover .project_link{
 opacity: 1; // transition from 0 opacity to 1
}
```

Comment: This is perfect!